# How to improve the speed resetting a minimax chess board implementation?

Tags: javascript, chess

I am programming a chess engine with minimax.

I use an array with 120 elements for the board. For every possible move, I have to create a copy of this array which is really slow without using bitboard.

Can I fasten this board copy part, e.g. using strings?

```
pisces.forEach(pisce=>{
    pisce.forEach(move=>{
          let copy=[...board]
          //other stuff
          board=copy
    })
})
```

Comment: What is *other stuff* doing with the `board` (or the `copy`)? And why do you overwrite the original `board` with the `copy` in every iteration?

Comment: I need to check every pisces every move for certain position in other stuff I have to play currently chosen move by currently chosen pisce on board and pass it to minimax board should reset every time or I would end up making multiple move from one side

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the board, you could consider using a "do-undo" system:

```
pisces.forEach(pisce=>{
    pisce.forEach(move=>{
        play(board, move);
        //other stuff
        undo(board, move);
    })
})
```

NB: in chess you need also to keep track of whether castling is still allowed, *en passent* capture is allowed, how many moves have passed since the last capture, pawn or castling move (for applying the 50-move rule), ... So a `move` object should have enough information to set and undo such state changes.

Comment: tanks a lot I had this problem with every other stuff like pistraking castle rights this helps a lot

Comment: Great question and answer. Would love to see the final implementation! Good luck!

Comment: This is the best way of doing it yes!